# How to open an Excel file, have the formulas be recalculated, then close it after some time?

Tags: python, subprocess, openpyxl

I need Python to open, save and then close an Excel file with the default software (e.g. MS Excel), because I need that Excel calculates some formulas, to read the numerical results within a Python code (I am using openpyxl).
In DOS I would write something like:

```
@echo off
start myfile.xlsx
timeout /t 8 /nobreak
some save here...
taskkill /im excel.exe /f
```

Is there a Pythonic way to do this? I need it for Windows, but it would be perfect if working also in other OS.

I had a look at the subprocess and os modules, but I found the documentation quite cryptic for me :-( especially when coming to waiting and then closing the process.

Comment: This doesn't make sense - merely opening and closing Excel isn't going to produce any results that can be read from Python, you'd at least have to tell it to save the changes to the file.  And what sort of calculation do you think Excel could do, that you couldn't do directly in Python?

Comment: I know it is weird, but this is my input and the unique alternative is to read the formulas from the Excel file and then convert them to python lines to calculate the results. Not sure it will be that fast to implement, because I have a pletora of different formulas in the input files!! I want to thanks, I didn't thought that I have also to save the file before closing it so I modify my question accordingly...

Comment: opening the excel file may cause macros to execute, aside from cells recalculating. if openpyxl is unable to execute cell formulas, this makes sense. -- perhaps there is a way to make openpyxl recalculate those cells as they are?

Comment: Openpyxl modifies Excel worksheets using OOXML, like editing the XML files data directly but using a MS API. There is nothing to make calculations. Using Xlwings or Win32com for the python app may have been more suitable, both interact with the worksheet through Excel.

Comment: @moken: Thanks for your suggestion! I tried xlwings and it does exactly what I need!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @moken suggestion, I used [xlwings](https://www.xlwings.org/), that also allows to open the excel file in background:

```
import xlwings as xw

app = xw.App(visible=False)
book = app.books.open(filename_with_path)
sheet = book.sheets[worksheet_name]
print(sheet['C5'].value)
book.save() ## note that saving is optional if you simply need to get the numbers from the Excel formulas
book.close()
app.quit()
```

This does all what I need!

Answer (score 0):

I think this code should solve your problem:

```
import os
import subprocess
import time

excel_file_path = "myfile.xlsx"
subprocess.Popen(["start", "excel", excel_file_path], shell=True)

time.sleep(8)

subprocess.Popen(["taskkill", "/im", "excel.exe", "/f"], shell=True)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works. Unluckily, what @jasonharper wrote is correct: I also need to save the changes before closing the Excel file to see the numbers... :-(

Comment: Aaah okei, hust a question: using excel is mandatory?

Comment: @BeginnerMe you can use pustil in subprocess to wait until the save changes is made.